# Show two label in nvd3 pie chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js, pie-chart

I need to show label inside and outside pie chart in nvd3.
I wish to visualise

[Pie chart as it should be](http://postimg.org/image/mmk781wwh/)

but I am able to show only one lable

[Pie chart result undesidered](http://postimg.org/image/toi4u90i9/)

This is the code I used:

```
chart = nv.models.pieChart()
  .x(function(d) {
    return $translate.instant(d.label);
  })
  .y(function(d) { return d.value })
  .showLabels(true)  //Display pie labels
  .color(function(d) {
    return myColors[d.label];
  })
  .labelThreshold(.05)  //Configure the minimum slice size for labels to show up
  .labelType("percent") //Configure what type of data to show in the label. Can be "key", "value" or "percent"
  .pieLabelsOutside(true)
  .donut(true)          //Turn on Donut mode. Makes pie chart look tasty!
  .donutRatio(0.05)     //Configure how big you want the donut hole size to be.
;
```